# What's common to pie crusts and deep fried battered foods?

Tags: pie, deep-frying

A member of my family gets migraines when he consumes certain foods. I'm trying to nail down which component of these foods is the trigger. What do pie crusts and deep fried battered foods (eg onion rings, fish and chips) have in common?

It's really puzzling me since there are so many similar foods that *don't* cause migraines for him, such as other fried foods (whether in oil or in butter) and other baked goods. And to make matters even more confusing, not all pie crusts and battered fried foods trigger him. I've looked through some lists of common dietary migraine triggers and none of them seem to fit. Gluten seems to be fine for him.

I made an all-butter pie crust tonight (just flour, butter, salt, and water) to see if it went over better than store bought crust, but alas, it triggered a migraine. I'm going to try making an all shortening one next.

What could be a common denominator in these foods? Any thoughts on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site @NewR. What makes you think it's the pie *crust* rather than what's in the pie?

Comment: Egg? ...........

Comment: Sorry my comment is not directly related, but you could probably keep a diary of the food intake with detailed ingredients, and log the migraine attacks as well. Like a tracker, iykwim. It might help in tracking down the common triggers.

Comment: @GdD: I'm pretty sure it's the crust because the migraines occur with different fillings. And the fillings are things that seem fine when consumed in other forms. For example, last night's pie was quiche. Eggs on their own have never been a problem. Ground beef pie can be a problem while shepherds pie with the same beef filling is fine.

Comment: @SF: eggs are fine for him on their own. Also, pie crusts typically don't contain eggs I believe.

Comment: @Ess Kay That's a good idea. I'm trying to keep better track now of which pie crust brands cause problems. Since they don't always cause problems, I'm really hoping there's some type of crust that's fine rather than the migraines being more idiosyncratic. I really love pie and hope I can keep making it for family dinners. :(  Thanks for the comments, guys!

Comment: Just for completeness @NewR could you post your pie crust recipe? Do you egg wash it?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question.  There are a finite number of ingredients that are common to fried food and pie crust (flour and fat...maybe salt).  However, whether or not they are related to migraines is impossible for us (or you) to know.  Your family member should visit his or her doctor.

Comment: Logically, if he only ate the pie crust (just flour, butter, salt, and water) and nothing else, and got a migraine, it must be one of those four or some combination, right? Also you need to confirm any additional ingredients in them.

Comment: @user3169 food is only one of many potential migraine triggers.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's maybe a particular compound that forms when those ingredients are heated together? Pie crust and fried food both have a high proportion of oil/fat, and are cooked at high heat (I think? Not so sure about deep frying temperatures), and maybe both contain flour. Flour and fat are fine in other foods so I wonder if something else arises (in higher concentrations) in these foods.

Comment: I don't think a doctor could help with this, it's more of a food chemistry question. A doctor would simply say to avoid your triggers, which is  what I hope to do-- while still consuming pie....! We're quite confident this is indeed a food trigger, the temporal association is strong (sometimes within a bite or two when severe). Here is the crust recipe. I did not use egg wash.  https://www.williams-sonoma.com/m/recipe/basic-pie-dough.html

Comment: Sorry, but there are thousands of things which are common and thousands which are uncommon, and a cook wouldn't know them. It could be a certain RAGE product of frying for all we know. So it falls under the "medical" category which we don't take on the site.